# How Can I sum up the column with decimal value in C# crystal report

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

Why is it not summing up. The datatype of totalamount due is decimal and When I insert a summary there is no sum in calculate summary.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it when i created a formula and convert it to Number and then Create another formula where it will hold the sum

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with C#, so I'm not sure about the decimal data type, but Crystal reports is treating your field totalamountdue as a string.  To get around this I'd create a simple formula then sum that instead:

```
if isnumeric({basetransactions1.totalamountdue})
then tonumber({basetransactions1.totalamountdue})
else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes crytsal report returns each data as string.

```
NumberVar value1 := yourValue;   
NumberVar value2 := yourValue;
```

NumberVar is crystal reports defined DataTypes.
*(here are some data types and conversions)*
http://ntssp.blogspot.com/2011/02/converting-data-types-in-crystal-report_16.html
This will treat your string data as numbers. and try doing your stuff.

Comment: Your link requires payment to see the full article. Please don't spam commercial links.